# turtlebot installation on ROS melodic

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have Ubuntu 18.04 and ROS melodic installed. I am trying to install turtle bot 3 software to ROS, but i only find the instruction for ROS indigo here: http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Turtlebot%20Installation
is there a version of turtle bot software that works with melodic, or where can i go to download ROS indigo? i try downloading previous ROS on Ubuntu 18.04 and it doesn't seems to work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293514/turtlebot-installation-on-ros-melodic/) by [Kevinlin980](https://answers.ros.org/users/35741/kevinlin980/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2018-06-07

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alex_f224](https://answers.ros.org/users/35926/alex_f224/) on 2018-07-12**:
Also looking for the "correct" answer for this question. But I did setup turtlbot3 for navigation task using this repo: https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3

Although the repo assumes kinetic, one could paste one package at a time into the workspace and see if it fits with Melodic.

**Comment by [alex_f224](https://answers.ros.org/users/35926/alex_f224/) on 2018-07-12**:
I included these packages: `turtlebot3_fake`  `turtlebot3_gazebo`  `turtlebot3_simulations` `turtlebot3_navigation`. I could not get gmapping to work but I could use an older laptop to map anyway.

**Comment by [teddybouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/581/teddybouch/) on 2018-07-25**:
I'm having the same problems with the same versions, and I'm not able to apt-get install any of those turtlebot3 packages. Browsing around the internet, it sounds like the turtlebot team is not supporting specific versions of ROS anymore, but I don't know how that affects installation.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
This link worked for me : https://automaticaddison.com/how-to-launch-the-turtlebot3-simulation-with-ros/
I could install turtlebot3 on Melodic with the help of above link and do some simple example.

---

Originally posted by [abtin](https://answers.ros.org/users/53254/abtin/) with karma: 31 on 2020-04-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Will your requirements satisfy by turtlebot3? Turtlebot3 is a new version of turtlebot.

If you want to install turtlebot3 ros package on your system, there are two ways:

1. Install as a binary package.

If you want to install it as a binary package, open your terminal and run the following command

`sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-turtlebot3-*`

2. The second method is to install the package from source. For that you need to clone the following Github package
   https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3
   into the 'src' folder of you catkin workspace and build the workspace using `catkin build` or `catkin_make`

---

Originally posted by [electrophod](https://answers.ros.org/users/43169/electrophod/) with karma: 277 on 2020-04-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anjishnu](https://answers.ros.org/users/61509/anjishnu/) on 2020-10-23**:
`sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-turtlebot3` worked for me

**Comment by [evilmind5](https://answers.ros.org/users/72504/evilmind5/) on 2021-03-26**:
sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-turtlebot3-*
has also worked for me! Thank you!